# Eigenvalue Question for Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I just took my midterm and I'm not quite sure about my reasoning for this question (or if the answer I gave was correct). I'm hoping someone can clarify for me.

${\bf Question}:$ Let $V$ be a two-dimensional, complex vector space and $T$ be a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$ such that $T^2 = -T^4$. What are the three possible eigenvalues of $T$?

I said that they were -$i$, $0$, and $i$. Does that seem correct?

Second part of the question: can a transformation $T$ have all three eigenvalues? I said no since three vectors cannot be linearly independent in a two-dimensional space and eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.

Answer (score 3):

No. Note that for any eigenvalue of $\lambda$ the following holds: If $x$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda$, we have $T^2x = \lambda^2 x$ and $T^4x = \lambda^4x$. As $T^2 = -T^4$, we have 
$$ 0 = (T^2 + T^4)x = (\lambda^2 + \lambda^4)x $$
and as $x \ne 0$, we must have $\lambda^2 + \lambda^4 = 0$. This holds for $\lambda = 0$, but not for $\lambda = \pm 1$.

---

After the question was edited: Yes, as $0$, $\pm i$ are the roots of $\lambda^4 + \lambda^2 = 0$, this are the only possible eigenvalues, you are also correct in saying they cannot occur all three due to the dimension of $\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: I mistyped my answer. I meant to say $i, -i, 0$. Is that correct?

Comment: Then edit your question to avoid misldeading others, @MatthewTurner

Comment: Fixed. I also added the second part of the question.

Comment: @MatthewTurner Edited my answer.